# What is the different between set something and set_something in tcl code

Tags: console, tcl

Hi guys I want to ask a supper newbie question here as I want to do my work without the need of learning tcl from scratch. I know that set is a command that assign value to the variable. However, I found a tcl code that use underscore between set and the variable. Ex set variable_x 1 and set_variable_x 1. Please explain me the different. I suspect the one with underscore (set_variable_x 1) is meant as a command to the console.

Here I include a better example

```
set charpoint chardir
create $charpoint

#Setup
set_log_file $charpoint/runTASK2.log
set_location  $charpoint 

#Copy configure.tcl into charpoint
exec cp configure.tcl ${charpoint}/config/configure.tcl
```

here you can see set charpoint have space and set_log_file dont have space but underscore between set and log_file

Answer (score 1):

`set` is a standard Tcl command, writing to a variable in the current scope (or reading from it if only one argument is given, an alternative to using `$`).

`set_something` is a command provided by an application or library. From the perspective of standard Tcl, it could do anything as commands aren't generally restricted; you'll need to look at the documentation of the other system for what it does and how to call it.

With names like that, I'd expect those to set some kind of variables behind the scenes (not necessarily in a place you can observe directly; there many options for that) but they might do quite a bit more besides; for example, it wouldn't be at all surprising if `set_log_file` opened an append-mode channel to the named file. It is possible to map such things to standard variables (maybe with some help from `trace`) but the authors of the application/library chose not to (or just didn't know that they could).

Comment: It's *possible* to replace the standard `set` command with your own, but probably a bad idea to do so. The chance of your code not working afterwards is very high. There are a very few cases where it is necessary though, and forbidding it would be against the general language philosophy.

Answer (score 1):

To Donal's answer I would add that a key to reading Tcl code is to realise that Tcl is structurally very simple - a script is an ordered set of commands (I'd say "list", but strictly it isn't exactly a `list` in the Tcl value sense).  Each command is an ordered set of words, the first of which is the command name and the rest are its arguments.  That's it - there are no reserved keywords or other magic, and the only syntax is the rules for resolving the set of commands and the words that comprise them.

In this way it's quite a lot like a shell script or DOS batch file if you are familiar with those contexts - a collection of commands and their arguments to run in order (but thankfully leaving out the quoting hell).

The Tcl interpreter provides a base collection of commands for many common things - `set`, `if`, `exec` etc, but that's all they are: commands like any other, and you can remove or redefine any of them.  Removing or redefining one of these default commands would usually be a horrible idea, but there are situations where it makes sense - perhaps you are implementing a DSL (Domain Specific Language) in which the `set` command declares some kind of mathematical set.  Users of your DSL probably don't think of themselves as writing Tcl scripts, so there is no problem with subverting the expectation that the `set` command does what it usually does in Tcl scripts.  It's this (very unusual) property of Tcl that makes it uniquely good as a base for these types of DSLs in my opinion.

But all that is to say: there is nothing special about the characters "set" that begin the command name `set_log_file` in your example - the "_" isn't "following" the `set` command, it's just part of the command name - which is everything in the first word of the command.  The command `set_log_file` isn't one of the builtins provided by the Tcl interpreter to all scripts, but from its name I'd guess that it configures the application to log to the file given in the first argument (the second word of the command: `$charpoint/runTASK2.log` in your example, which would be resolved by the interpreter to substitute the variable reference `$charpoint` with the value it contains at that point in the execution of the program, before handing off the result as the value of the argument to the `set_log_file` command implementation).

Note that this probably isn't how most Tcl programmers think about the language structure (unless their minds were previously corrupted by exposure to lisp) but it's worth trying to adjust your mental model to align with what is actually going on.  Despite it's superficial similarities to C (Algol) family languages it's really a very different beast.  Once you get that mental interpreter switch right everything about the language is obvious and clear.  There are a lot of languages I love, but Tcl most of all.  But it took learning it a second time to see its beauty.